# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() - Android Marmalade

Tags: java, marmalade

I'm trying to add USB controller support to my Android game. I'm using Marmalade and I've created an extension based on the USB example code. Here it is:

```
public class GameControllerInput extends Activity
             implements InputManager.InputDeviceListener 
{
    private static final String TAG = "GameControllerInput";

    private InputManager mInputManager;
    private SparseArray<InputDeviceState> mInputDeviceStates;

    private static int numEvents = 0;


    public int EDK_GameControllerInput_Init()
    {
        LoaderActivity.m_Activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {
        public void run()
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Running 1 =========================");
        }
    });
    Log.i(TAG, "Init 2 =========================");
    return 1;
```

When I call the init function I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

I've read other threads with this error and they say the solution is to add the `LoaderActivity.m_Activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()` code. However, as you can see, adding this just gives me the same error.

I'm not experienced with Java and I'm at a loss on how to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

A `Looper` (a message queue processor) is tied to a single thread, each thread has at most one looper. A `Handler` needs to register itself with a `Looper` to work, so each time you invoke `new Handler()`, it tries to get the `Looper` for the current thread (the thread that's creating the `Handler`), which can be either present or not. The exception that you see is thrown because the thread that's creating the handler does not have a looper.

There is one two things that you can do to fix this:

- Add a `Looper` to the current thread.
- Make sure you're creating the `Handler` on a thread that already has a `Looper`.

In almost all cases, the handler is used to communicate from a background thread to the UI thread, I'm assuming that's the case here. That means option 2. Your `runOnUiThread(Runnable)` thing is close, but no cigar, because all it does is write to the log file.

You need to move the code that creates the `new Handler()` (not shown in your posted code sample) into the `runOnUiThread` block, or use some other way to get it to run on the UI thread. The typical way to do this is to create it in the `onCreate(Bundle)` method of your activity or fragment.

Keep in mind that, depending on your initialization order, this may mean it's initially `null` as seen by your background thread, so the background code will have to be able to deal with that.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have any code the relates to a Handler. This is just example code I've copied from the NDK. I'm a total Java noob (hence why I choose to use Marmalade). Can you point me at some example code that shows a handler being used?

Comment: I wrote [a short piece about loopers](http://blog.xebia.com/2013/02/24/android-looper-anatomy/) awhile back, but it may not give you enough info. If the goal of the handler is to get on the UI thread, there's actually an easy way to get the Handler initialized correctly: `new Handler( Looper.getMainLooper() )`. This will work regardless of which is the calling thread.

I am unfamiliar with the Marmalade framework, so I don't know where or when it initializes its handlers. I figure there has to be somekind of init or startup method that you don't currently invoke on the main thread, but should.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this more. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @ColdBeamGames: Remember that if this answer helped to upvote it and if it solved your problem to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's better to have a callback method and mark it as main thread only by calling `run_on_os_thread` after the method declaration in `s4e` file.